# EF6 Data Seeding Issue with System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddOrUpdate

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2016

EF 6.2,
SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition,
.Net 4.5.2

I'm running into some issues with the [AddOrUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846514(v=vs.103).aspx) extension method. 
As I understand the method, one should define, with a lambda expression, the unique field that should be used to determine if a record is to be updated or added. But mine seems to be ignoring this and trying to add every time. This example is using the Identity class AspNetRole but the same issue is happening for all entities in the context.

```
public class UserSeeder
{    
    public static void Seed(MyIdentityDbContext context)
    {


        HashSet<AspNetRole> roles = new HashSet<AspNetRole>();

        AspNetRole systemAdmin = new AspNetRole() { Id = "269E684F-9542-4F6A-8029-7516AA2ECD61", Name = "System Admin" };
        AspNetRole admin = new AspNetRole() { Id = "BE70FDF9-FCD5-4894-AE71-DA324A7D751E", Name = "Administrator" };
        AspNetRole normalUser = new AspNetRole() { Id = "D9C66DC0-190F-463A-88B0-8E1E4ED96BAF", Name = "User" };

        roles.Add(systemAdmin);
        roles.Add(admin);
        roles.Add(normalUser);

        foreach (AspNetRole role in roles)
        {
            context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(r =>r.Id, role);
            //context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(role);
            //both throw same error
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And in the Configuration.cs file generated by Enabling Migrations.

```
//  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.
protected override void Seed(MyIdentityDbContext context)
{
    UserSeeder.Seed(context);
    base.Seed(context);
}
```

This is the error I'm getting for both the call using the lambda and just passing in the object. I have a suspicion there is some configuration I'm not setting correctly cause this was working last week and when I check git, no changes have been made to any of the DAL project's files.

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.AspNetRoles'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetRoles'. The duplicate key value is (269E684F-9542-4F6A-8029-7516AA2ECD61).

Additionally, the db is up-to-date and the application doesn't throw any data access errors in runtime so the connection is fine and the model is in sync. We just can't get the seed method to work the way the examples show.

Comment: What happens if you call `context.saveChanges()` after your three `roles.Add` calls (in addition to doing it below)

Comment: This is the error that is thrown when context.saveChanges() is called. either in the loop or after all are added.

`Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.AspNetRoles'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetRoles'. The duplicate key value is (269E684F-9542-4F6A-8029-7516AA2ECD61).`

Comment: I mean call `SaveChanges` after the three `Add` calls in addition to calling it after the foreach loop:
    
         `roles.Add(systemAdmin);
         roles.Add(admin);
         roles.Add(normalUser);
         roles.SaveChanges();`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the role is already exist if exist then update else add new role

```
    public static void Seed(MyIdentityDbContext context)
    {
        HashSet<AspNetRole> roles = new HashSet<AspNetRole>();
        AspNetRole systemAdmin = new AspNetRole() { Id = "269E684F-9542-4F6A-8029-7516AA2ECD61", Name = "System Admin" };
        AspNetRole admin = new AspNetRole() { Id = "BE70FDF9-FCD5-4894-AE71-DA324A7D751E", Name = "Administrator" };
        AspNetRole normalUser = new AspNetRole() { Id = "D9C66DC0-190F-463A-88B0-8E1E4ED96BAF", Name = "User" };

        roles.Add(systemAdmin);
        roles.Add(admin);
        roles.Add(normalUser);

        foreach (AspNetRole role in roles)
        {
            AspNetRole dbrole = context.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id.ToLower() == role.Id.ToLower());
            if (dbrole != null)
            {
                dbrole.Name = role.Name;
                context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(dbrole);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Roles.Add(role);
            }           
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this throws the same error. It's still sending an update through AddOrUpdate which is the what is not working.

Comment: you can use Sql profiler to check the query sent by ef @KennyLucero

Comment: @Kenny lucero just updated my answer could you please check it